# Figma: flattened vector exports as multiple paths

Tags: vector, svg, figma

I flatten multiple vectors into one, so it appears in Figma as follows:

[image]

However when I export it to SVG, this vector appears as multiple paths in SVG markup. Is the a way in Figma to make it a single path? Or maybe you can recommend other editor that is able to do it?

Comment: I don't usually have problems exporting svg from figma... what is the actual shape you're exporting?

Comment: City skyline - buildings with windows, and buildings are flattened into a single shape as shown in the image above, yet in svg, they are still made up of multiple paths.

Comment: Can you try grouping all paths and than export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figma doesn't handle flattening shapes the same way Illustrator does.

It uses booleans for merging 2 shapes together, as a non-destructive way to create a new shape. Unfortunately, you'd need to take this into a program like illustrator to create a fully custom shape, or use the pen tool to trace it.